# Using wp_dropdown_users and selected() function?

Tags: dropdown

I have a custom meta box with a dropdown displaying all the WP users via wp_dropdown_users. It saves which WP user is chosen with the post, so that all works.

However, is there a way to make it show the selected user in the dropdown when going back to edit, rather than the first in the list? I've used the selected() function for another dropdown but I've created that dynamically. I've tried to implement selected() with wp_dropdown_users, but it hasn't worked so I'm not sure if it's even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `selected` argument for the `wp_dropdown_users` function. Do it like this:

```
wp_dropdown_users( array( 
    // ...
    'selected' => $user_id,
    // ...
) );
```

Read documentation for [wp_dropdown_users](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_users) function

Comment: Thank you! I thought it was that at first but I thought it required an actual ID number. End of semester, brain not working right. Thanks again!